# Prevent item from showing up in string LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a list of prices that is based off of products which are in categories. I need to make sure those prices of products in sub-categories do not show up in this list, but they are. Sub-categories and categories are in the same table in the db, the only difference is that a sub-category will have a parent ID to show that it's a child.

I have these 2 LINQ statements that I need to tie together somehow and I can't get it right. Maybe I am not trying to do this the right way, but I'm not very experienced with LINQ yet and I haven't been able to find much help online.

To be clear, this is not for removing duplicates, I don't have that problem, I just need to prevent some of the results from showing up.

```
var subCategories = siteCategory.SiteSubCategories.Where(x => x.Active);
string lowestPrice = siteCategory.SiteProducts.Min(x => x.Price).ToString();
```

I have tried to do the following
    string lowestPrice = siteCategory.SiteProducts.Where(!subCategories).Min(x => x.Price).ToString();
but I get an error saying `Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'IEnumerable'`

I've also tried multiple other combinations of linq statements, too many to list, so I just listed the one that I tried which made the most sense to me.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is product related with a category?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to retrieve and what you are trying to eliminate. Your subCategories var contains a list of all active Categories. Where are you gong with the prices.. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm trying to retrieve a list of prices based on products in a category and a category only. The list I have currently is pulling in prices from products in sub-categories as well. I need to eliminate any price from a product within a sub-category. When I debug the `var subCategories` brings back a list of sub-categories which is good. The `string lowestPrice` brings back the lowest price of each product, but I need to tell lowestPrice to leave out any product within a subCategory.

Comment: The two answers below will work, Pedros is the cleaner solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a lambda with .Where. That part of the code should be something like

```
siteCategory.SiteProducts
    .Where(product => !subCategories.contains(product.Category))
    .Min(x => x.Price).ToString()
```

with the appropriate way of getting the category of a product. I guessed at `product.Category`, you'll need to update that piece yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of how your data is modeled, but assuming that `Product` has a `Category` property. And that `Category` has a `ParentId` nullable property, you could do:

```
siteProducts
  .Where(product => product.Category.ParentId == null)
  .Min(product => product.Price)
  .ToString();
```